# Writer: Highlight matches

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice-writer

LibreOffice 3.4 seems to have a simplified Search toolbar instead of the old popup dialogue. This toolbar does not have a "Highlight matches" function, nor can I find such an option or button to add to the toolbar. How can one highlight all matches in LibreOffice 3.4?

**EDIT:** My goal is not to change the style of all the matched text, but rather to have them shown in a conspicuous fashion. For instance, if you use the Chrome web browser, try typing Ctrl-F and performing a search. Notice that all the matching text is highlighted. This is the effect that I am looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The Find & Replace dialog can be activated by keying `ctrl`-`alt`-`F` or by clicking the icon on the Standard toolbar. This dialog can be used to globally search for a word or phrase and replace it with the same word or phrase with different format (for example, a yellow background.) Choose More Options in the dialog to access the format options. That would highlight all matches. This highlighting can be reversed by `ctrl`-`z`, or Edit/Undo.

I also see that the simplified search toolbar has a Find & Replace button that is not visible by default. You can choose to make it visible by right-clicking on some of the simplified search toolbar's icons, or on the pull-down menu at the right of the toolbar.

Comment: Thank you, but apparently I did not ask a clear question! My goal is not to change the style of all the matched text, but rather to have them shown in a conspicuous fashion. For instance, if you use the Chrome web browser, try typing Ctrl-F and performing a search. Notice that all the matching text is highlighted. This is the effect that I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I provided a method to do it. Changing the style does highlight the matched text in a conspicuous fashion. And you can undo the change with ctrl-z. This is functionally equivalent to the Chrome ctrl-f function, although is more work to make happen.